# Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, null-pointer

There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was:

> Apex trigger updatequotestatus caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: updatequotestatus: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.updatequotestatus line 5, column 1.

Error Occured at Line:

**`if((t.what.getsobjecttype() == quote__c.sobjecttype) && (t.subject.substring(0,5) == 'Email')`**

```
trigger updatequotestatus on task (after insert, after update){
    Set<Id> quoteIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<quote__c> quotes = new List<quote__c>();

    for(task t:trigger.new){
        if(t.whatId!=null){
            if((t.what.getsobjecttype() == quote__c.sobjecttype) && (t.subject.substring(0,5) == 'Email')){
                quoteIds.add(t.whatId);
            }
        }
    }

    for(quote__c q:[select StageName__c from quote__c where Id IN : quoteIds]){
        quote__c qt = new quote__c();
        qt.Id = q.Id;
        qt.StageName__c = 'Proposal Sent';
        quotes.add(qt);
    }

    if(quotes.size()>0){
        update quotes;
    }
}
```

Comment: [NullPointerExceptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) are pretty straightforward. You are referencing a variable that is not initialised or has been set to null. There are not many variables in `if((t.what.getsobjecttype()==quote__c.sobjecttype) && (t.subject.substring(0,5)=='Email')` so I suggest you do some debugging (e.g. printout the value of `t.what`) to see what is null in that line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T.what` is null, because you haven't queried for it, and the relationships passed into a trigger are always null. Instead, you can call getSobjectType on WhatId directly:

```
if(t.WhatId != NULL && t.WhatId.getSobjectType() == Quote__c.SobjectType ...
```

**Bonus:** 
Also, since you aren't checking for any of the data from the query, there's strictly no reason to waste a query here:

```
for(Id quoteId: quoteIds) {
    Quote__c q = new Quote__c(Id=quoteId);
    ...
```

Comment: where i have to change my trigger any suggestions plz..

Comment: @Sathya As the answer says, change t.what.get... to t.whatid.get...